# How to see broker information when using Flower?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, flower

I am running flower by the command:

`celery flower --broker=amqp://<username>:<password>@localhost:5672/<virtualhostname> --broker_api=http://<username>:<password>@localhost:5672/api/`

I can see the tasks info, the worker info etc.

But as soon as I go to `/broker`, I see the error in console:

`RabbitMQ management API call failed: Stream closed`

and the UI remains blank with no data.

Interestingly whenever I go to `/monitor`, I see the same error in the console, however, after a couple of seconds graphs gets to load on the monitor page.

But for broker page nothing happens even after waiting.

The broker I am using is `RabbitMQ` and the management plugin is already enabled for the broker by the command:
`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

Why am I getting the Stream closed error for the broker page?

Associated github issue: https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/830

Answer (score 8):

In the `broker_api` URL, you use `5672` port, but RabbitMQ management API usually listens on different port, `15672` (see [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#usage-ui)). Also, the user you use has to be granted `management` permission (see [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#permissions))

Answer (score 0):

In the RabbitMQ management web-page - you should look at the user rights. It's important that the user flower is using has access to "Virtual hosts".